# How to get items in between from a list

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a arraylist and i have to get some items in between the list i.e., for example a list of 50 items and i have to display few items from 35 to 45 or from some other range. how it is possible to get sequence of items from the list.,

Any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be using [List.get(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int))

Comment: What kind of selection you have do, make it clear. And show your progress.

Comment: @Harry Joy thanks bro, List.get(int index) will get a particular item alone but how to get in sequences to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sequence-get. Use get in a loop. for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    myVar[i] = myList.get(i);  //stupid example... I know.
}
```

In your case you could do:

```
for (int i = 35; (i < myList.size() || i < 45); i++) {
    myVar[i-35] = myList.get(i);  //stupid example... I know.
}
```

But put those *magic numbers* into variables.

Edit:

```
for (int i = lowerBorder; (i < myList.size() || i < upperBorder); i++) {
    myVar[i-lowerBorder] = myList.get(i);  //stupid example... I know.
}
```

Comment: thanks, i have a spinner with 5-10, 10-15, 15-20 etc and when i click 15-20 it should display 15 -20 itmes alone, how to pass that from spinner, any idea

Comment: Read the values from that spinner entry and wrap it into variables like 'int lowerBorder = 15' and int upperBorder = 20'.

Answer (score 0):

THis is what I'd normally do. You first convert the ArrayList to an Array. For Example..

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrList=new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Creating ArrayList
arrList.add(1); arrList.add(100); arrList.add(1000); //Adding items to ArrayList
Integer[] intArr=arrList.toArray(new Integer[arrList.size()]); //Convert ArrayList to Array
```

Now all you have to do is access intArray as anyother integer Array. For instance, 
intArr[3] will give you 1000.